# Converting positive and negative values to a bitstring using numpy.clip

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, clip

I want to efficiently convert values from a list (or numpy array) into a numpy array of bits: A negative value should become a 0 in the new array, and a positive value a 1 in the new array.

E.g.,

```
>> import numpy as np
>> np.clip([1,2,3,-1,-2],  a_min=0, a_max=1)
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

However, if I have floats in the list, this method keeps them as is:

```
>> np.clip([1,0.45,3,-1,-2],  a_min=0, a_max=1)
array([ 1.  ,  0.45,  1.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ])
```

Is there a good way of circumventing this behavior? One way would be to round the values. But I would want everything that is positive assigned a 1. If I would use `np.around()`, this would round 0.45 -> 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To map everything greater than 0 to 1 (and everything less to 0) you could use [np. where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [25]: np.where(np.array([1,0.45,3,-1,-2]) > 0, 1, 0)
Out[25]: array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

or

```
In [29]: (np.array([1,0.45,3,-1,-2]) > 0).astype('i1')
Out[29]: array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int8)
```

Note that `np.where` is returning an array with dtype `int32` (4-byte ints), while `astype('i1')` is returning an array with dtype `int8` (1-byte ints).

If you wish to pack these binary values into a uint8, you could use [np.packbits](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html):

```
In [48]: x = np.array([1,0.45,3,-1,-2])

In [49]: np.packbits((x > 0).astype('i1'))
Out[49]: array([224], dtype=uint8)

In [50]: bin(224)
Out[50]: '0b11100000'
```

Or, as a string:

```
In [60]: np.packbits((x > 0).astype('i1')).tostring()
Out[60]: '\xe0'

In [62]: bin(0xe0)
Out[62]: '0b11100000'
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! I will accept this answer when StackOverflow lets me!

Comment: Note that, if performance is a concern, I'm getting that `(a > 0).astype('i1')` is much faster than `np.where(a > 0, 1, 0)`. The difference is larger the bigger the array is. I'm getting about 2x faster for a 100-length array, up to 10x faster for a 10k-length array.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [21]: arr = np.array([1,0.45,3,-1,-2])

In [22]: np.ceil(arr.clip(0, 1))
Out[22]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.])
```